# populating field A with content of field B

Tags: tokens

I have a content type with several fields, e.g. phone1 and phone2.

I would like to populate another type of field, "table_field", with values from the first two automatically, on creation of an instance of this content type.

What would be the best way? Can I utilize tokens to do this? Thanks for your time, I appreciate it. This is my first project. Huge learning curve, and am enjoying it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Drupal 6 you could use [Computed Field](http://drupal.org/project/computed_field) for that, but unfortunately it's not completely ready for Drupal 7 yet.

You could also create a custom module in which you implement [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) to set the value of 'field A' based on the value of 'field B'. When you choose this method, you may also want to implement hook_form_alter to hide field A from the node form.

Comment: I have been looking for a small and "simple" project with which to start learning how to code a module. It may well be that your suggestion fits the bill perfectly. Thanks for pointing out the hooks.

Comment: Punchy: thanks for the feedback. Hooks like these are indeed a nice way to start coding for Drupal. JoeS: thanks for the hint!

Comment: I'm afraid I am still too junior to vote. I will, however, check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Now computed field has Drupal 7 version, I compare it with dynamic field and I it's it's better. Check out this post: [Calculate Field Values Using Computed Field in Drupal 7](http://miss-hana.com/calculate-field-values-using-computed-field-in-drupal-7/).

And here's an example of using [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7):

```
function MODULE_NAME_node_presave($node){
  if ($node->type === 'NODE_TYPE'){
    $node->FIELD_COMPUTED['und'][0]['value'] = 
    $node->FIELD_COMPUTED_A['und'][0]['value'] +
    $node->FIELD_COMPUTED_B['und'][0]['value'];
  }
}
```